# Lifetime for the view / viewmodel when using data templates

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am defining a strategy where a main view will use data templates to switch between the views. Currently it can switch between 3 Views:

- ApplicationView: it is actually the view that consists of lots of
  different views, mostly layered out using tabs / docking. this is a
  view that deals with application data.
- LogInView: it is used for logging the user in.
- DialogView: it is used to display dialog views. This view will also use data templates to select a proper view that is required.

The idea is that when a dialog view needs to be displayed, it is set as current view on the main view. After the selection is done, this information is passed to ApplicationView, or a view that is part of ApplicationView. While DialogView is shown, ApplicationView, must not be released from memory, since it ApplicationViewModel will still be manipulating with data (it needs to constantly work in the background).

I am thinking of achieving this using DataTemplates, and binding ContentControl's Content to CurrentView:

```
// in MainView
DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ApplicationViewModel}">
    <vw:ApplicationView />
</DataTemplate>

.....

// in MainViewModel
public ViewModelBase CurrentView { get; set; }
```

Basically I am trying to avoid using modal windows for dialogs.

1) Is this strategy OK, or there are some problems that I am not aware with it?

2) When I switch to DialogView (I am actually switching viewmodels), what happens with the ApplicationView/ApplicationViewModel? Do I need to store ApplicationViewModel's reference somewhere, so it doesn't get garbage collected? I haven't tested this, but probably when I set CurrentView a new instance of ViewModel/View will be created.

3) Connected to second question, when using DataTemplates, what happens to View/ ViewModel that was previously used, and is now replaced with different view/viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see anything wrong with the way you're switching views, although typically you don't want to get rid of the application when you're displaying a dialog.

   What I've done in the past is to put both the `CurrentView`, and the `DialogView` in a `Grid` so they are positioned on top of each other, then have the `ApplicationViewModel` contain an `IDialogViewModel` and `IsDialogVisible` properties, and when you want to display the dialog simply populate those two fields. (see below for an example)
2. You will have to store the `ApplicationViewModel` somewhere if you want to go back to it and avoid creating a new `ApplicationViewModel`
3. WPF disposes of UI objects that are no longer visible, so switching the `CurrentView` from `Login` to `Application` will get rid of the `LoginView` and create an `ApplicationView`

   The ContentControl's Content is getting set to your `ViewModel`, so the ViewModel is actually being put in the applications `VisualTree`. Whenever WPF encounters an object in its `VisualTree` that it doesn't know how to draw, it will draw it using a `TextBlock` containing the `.ToString()` of the the object. By defining a `DataTemplate`, you are telling WPF how to draw the object instead of using its default `.ToString()` method. Once the object leaves the `VisualTree`, any visual objects that were created to render the object will get destroyed.

Although I would keep using what you currently have for switching Views, I would not use that method for the `Login`, `Application`, and `Dialog` views.

Typically the `LoginView` should only be displayed once when logging in, although it might get displayed again in a `Dialog` if you allow users to switch logins once logging in. Because of this, I typically show the `LoginView` in the startup code, then display the `ApplicationView` once login is successful.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var login = new LoginDialog();
    var loginVm = new LoginViewModel();

    login.DataContext = loginVm;
    login.ShowDialog();

    if (!login.DialogResult.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    // Providing we have a successful login, startup application
    var app = new ApplicationView();
    var context = new ApplicationViewModel(loginVm.CurrentUser);
    app.DataContext = context;
    app.Show();
}
```

Like I said earlier, I wouldn't want to hide the `Application` when I display a `Dialog`, so I would make the `Dialog` part of the `Application`

Here's an example of the `DataTemplate` I would use for my `ApplicationViewModel`, using my own [custom Popup from my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) for the Dialog

```
<Grid x:Name="ApplicationView">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    <local:PopupPanel x:Name="DialogPopup"
                      Content="{Binding DialogContent}"
                      local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsDialogVisible}"
                      local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=ApplicationView}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, the application itself should "never" be closed, so log in should be done during the application run on each shift change. This is why I want to make LoginView part of application. So, if I understood you correctly, ApplicationView will going to be disposed as soon as I switch the CurrentView, no matter if I keep the reference to ApplicationViewModel to prevent it from being disposed? But if I hide the view, the view will not be disposed?

Comment: @Goran I see, in that case I would simply make the `Login` as one of the dialog popups or perhaps even one of the `CurrentViews` for the application. `ApplicationView` will get unloaded if it is not visible, either through having its `Visibility` property set to something non-visible, or through changing the `CurrentView` so it doesn't exist. If you have data that you want saved, you should be storing it in the `ApplicationViewModel`, so next time you display the `ApplicationView` it will load back to wherever the user last was.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would find it easier to use ZOrdering within a standard grid, and put everything in the same view - using the ViewModel to manage visibility.

E.g

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsView1Visible, 
        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <!-- view 1 contents -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsView2Visible, 
        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <!-- view 2 contents -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsView3Visible, 
        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <!-- view 3 contents -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsDialogVisible, 
        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <!-- dialog contents contents -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This gets really complex with many different Views, and is much more work since you have to manage View visibility manually. I find its much more efficient to use `DataTemplates` to define how each `ViewModel` should be drawn, display a `CurrentView` property in a `ContentControl`, then just set the `CurrentView` to whatever `ViewModel` is current. I have an example [on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) if you're interested